How does boost::interprocess::offset_ptr avoid undefined behaviour?
Update: Adding details about boost's implementation.
The NullableOffsetPtr idea is inspired by boost::interprocess::offset_ptr.
To which extent can their implementation deal with the restrictions of expr.add#4.2 and avoid UB?

Found the term "illegal but correct" in the context of inlining:

   //Note: using the address of a local variable to point to another address
   //is not standard conforming and this can be optimized-away by the compiler.
   //Non-inlining is a method to remain illegal but correct


However I'm neither understanding how inlining relates to UB, nor whether there is a widely accepted illegal correctness, that could be verified.

boost::interprocess::offset_ptr does all arithmetics using uintptr_t, avoiding the contraints of expr.add#4.2 entirely. At least for T <-> offset_ptr<T> conversions it also guarantees a round trip, i.e. the pointer is reproduced from the same integral value, that resulted from the initial pointer to integral conversion. That's just a consequence of arithmetic operations being inverse, so with reinterpret_cast Explanation item 3) stating


is guaranteed to have its original value

sounds sufficient to be well defined? I doubt whether this also holds for increment/decrement operators of offset_ptr, but that's of minor relevance for me.

Performs conversions via helper functions using const volatile void* arguments. So reinterpret_cast never connects T* and uintptr_t directly, but always seems to have a void type at in- or output.

Can you help me understanding whether and which of these techniques are relevant for defined vs. undefined behavior?

while i can't answer how their technique counters UB when UB is present, its practical use in IPC is not UB because you allocate a large chunk of char[] for IPC and all the pointers are technically within one very large array.

@AhmedAEK when using SHM it's even less: mmap returning a void* to memory I can then construct my object into, using placement new. No array. I'm still confused about how this help in practical use. None of my calculated offset values have ever been wrong, even in cases of demonstrated and observable UB. Instead the compiler concluded equal pointers can't be equal because I stupidly targeted local variables. Well, that one is ironed out now.

What about "Technically UB, but passing all tests for every supported compiler since 2005". So only "slightly illegal". Will your code be equally well-tested? :-)

@BoP, is this what Boost does? That would be perfectly acceptable, if there is no alternative, but must be deliberate choice. I'm afraid, no matter how well-tested code I produce, I'd have some effort getting away with this justification.

@BoP, my class is stupid simple, so I understand how it works. Boost's offset_ptr is far more generic, 15 times the amount of code, so I'm asking for assistance to learn how it works.

@Michael - I'm not a Boost expert, so cannot tell how they came to this code. Theoretically, being an insider you might be able to consult the compiler writers and get advice on what would happen. Or even check the open source compiler yourself!

@MichaelSteffens malloc implicitly creates objects of implicit-lifetime type as necessary, e.g. an array of char. If you placement-new something later, then it may be nested in such an array. Pointer subtraction in type char is then fine. Reforming the pointer is only possible if it is done starting with a pointer to the backing array instead of the newed object and only with std::launder applied after the cast.

The behavior of integer/pointer casts, especially if integer arithmetic is involved, is underspecified. See discussion e.g. in https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2318r1.pdf. It is not clear what should or shouldn't be UB. As you note the current C++ specification should allow the round-trip conversion to the same object as long as the integer value at the end is the same, but that isn't actually implementable, because multiple objects have the same address (which in practice is the integer value). See https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2434r0.html.

Preventing inlining is only meant to prevent the compiler from being able to see the surrounding code when optimizing the function, so that it can't be "clever" by using that the function has UB for the actually used arguments/context. Generally compilers emit every function only once and it has to work correctly in every context in which it is called. So it has to use general/straight-forward machine instructions to implement it. But I would not be sure that this generally works. Things like IPA, LTO etc. might interfere, especially with internal linkage. UB isn't affected.
